# Insert Ads After Every X Paragraphs PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, ads

I am currently using this code to insert Ads after the 5th paragraph and it works just fine.

```
//Insert ads after fifth paragraph
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads' );
function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {
    $ad_code = '<center>AD CODE</center>';
    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
        return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 5, $content );
    }
    return $content;
}

// Parent Function
function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
    $closing_p = '</p>';
    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
    foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {
        if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
        }
        if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
        }
    }
    return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```

But, I would like the ads to be repeated after every 5 paragraphs, not just once. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
```

you can use

```
if ( $index % $paragraph_id === 0 ) {
```

that should do it.

Comment: Thanks but it is repeating the Ads after every 1 paragraph, not 5 paragraphs.

Comment: Sorry for that, I've updated the code. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Not working, It is causing "Critical Error on the website"

Comment: Sorry for that ... the error was division by 0, because paragraph_id was smaller then index ... I've replaced them. It should work now.

Comment: Thanks, @Anwar S. The replaced snippet actually works just fine.

Comment: Hi again @Answar S. How can I make this code not appear after the first paragraph?